# How do I use 'Where In' in Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, sql, orm, dapper

I've been trying unsuccessfully now for a while to use an `IEnumerable<string>` with a `WHERE IN` clause in Dapper.

In the documentation, it does say that `IEnumerable<int>` is supported for use in a `WHERE IN` but I can't even get that to work.

[`Dapper allow you to pass in IEnumerable<int> and will automatically parameterize your query.`](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

The error message I keep receiving is an Sql syntax error. `Incorrect syntax near ','.`

I've put together some test code that I hope will demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

---

```
string connString = "Server=*.*.*.*;Database=*;User Id=*;Password=*;";

string sqlStringIn = @"SELECT StringText FROM 
                (SELECT 1 ID, 'A' StringID, 'This is a test' StringText
                UNION SELECT 2 ID, 'B' StringID, 'Another test' StringText
                UNION SELECT 3 ID, 'C' StringID, 'And another' StringText
                UNION SELECT 4 ID, 'D' StringID, 'and again' StringText
                UNION SELECT 5 ID, 'E' StringID, 'yet again' StringText) data
                WHERE StringId IN (@str)";

string sqlIntegerIn = @"SELECT StringText FROM 
                (SELECT 1 ID, 'A' StringID, 'This is a test' StringText
                UNION SELECT 2 ID, 'B' StringID, 'Another test' StringText
                UNION SELECT 3 ID, 'C' StringID, 'And another' StringText
                UNION SELECT 4 ID, 'D' StringID, 'and again' StringText
                UNION SELECT 5 ID, 'E' StringID, 'yet again' StringText) data
                WHERE ID IN (@integer)";


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    List<int> integers = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
    List<string> strings = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };

    var parameters = new {str = strings, integer = integers };

    //fails here
    IEnumerable<string> intTest = conn.Query<string>(sqlIntegerIn, parameters, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text);

    //and here
    IEnumerable<string> stringTest = conn.Query<string>(sqlStringIn, parameters, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Linq ? There is a helper library for Dapper that does the job for you : http://sqlinq.codeplex.com/releases/view/88056

Comment: @Aybe there's no need to; dapper explicitly handles this situation

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To do what is needed here, dapper needs to alter the SQL on the fly - so it needs to be *really* sure that it is doing the right thing. The regular valid SQL syntax includes parenthesis:

```
WHERE StringId IN (@str)
```

To disambiguate from this, the *voodoo dapper syntax* **omits** the parenthesis:

```
WHERE StringId IN @str
```

If it detects this, it looks for a parameter called `str`, and expands it, to one of:

```
WHERE 1=0 -- if no values
WHERE StringId = @str -- if exactly one value
WHERE StringId IN (@str0, @str1, ...) -- if more than one value
```

But short version: remove the parenthesis.

Comment: @Marc does this not fall over if the list in exceeds a maximum? See error: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100

Comment: @csetzkorn if you are using very large sets, a TVP and `INNER JOIN` is probably a much better idea than `IN`; dapper has full support for TVPs. What I don't want to do is hard-code every different vendor's different technical limits into the library

Comment: Thanks TVP sounds good. I suppose I can just include it in my parametised sql? (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466485/generic-parameterised-sql-query-with-dapper)

Comment: Thanks. I am still not sure how to do it. Can you please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468710/use-table-valued-parameter-tvp-instead-of-where-in

Comment: @MarcGravell does that only work if there's only one IEnumerable parameter on the passed in object, or can there be other properties too? `var parameters = new { assemblyName, entityIds = listOfIds.ToArray() };`

Comment: @jcolebrand it should be fine with arbitrary numbers, as long as they don't exceed the parameter limits of the provider

Comment: @MarcGravell rubber duck debugging last night revealed operator error :-\ feel free to destroy these three comments for me

Comment: @MarcGravell I have been using this functionality and it seems very slow. It is usually taking over 600 ms for one simple select. Straight T-SQL takes under 10 ms.  Should we use Dapper.DBString in some way? Also, my list is always 10 items or less.

Comment: @Ben if the database is varchar rather than nvarchar, then yes: DbString. If you use varchar extensively, IIRC we exposed a default setting.

Comment: @MarcGravell That helps. What is the default setting?  I know how to use DbString but how is it done with an array?

Comment: @Ben I'm not at a PC, but I would expect an array of DbString to work...

Comment: Does it works in ExecuteScalar extension too? Using the suggested syntax it gives me the "incorrect syntax" runtime exception.

Comment: Worth calling out that the rationale for this behavior is more fully explained @ https://code.google.com/archive/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/114.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add an important note if you are interested in being able to handle an empty list, aka make the `IN` clause `optional`. I did this by adding a property to contain the count such as `public int InClauseCount => InClauseList?.Length ?? 0;`

Then use the count within the sql like this...

```
Select field1, field2
from Table1
where (some condition)
AND (@InClauseCount = 0 OR field1 IN @InClauseList)
```

I hope this can help someone out there. I spent a little too long trying to solve this, partially because I'm new to Dapper.